# It does not redirect to the show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**historys_controller.rb**

```
class Facturacion::HistorysController < Facturacion::AuthorizeController
#before_filter :student, :only => :show,:index
skip_load_and_authorize_resource 
authorize_resource  :only => [:index, :show]
layout 'facturacion/dashboard_layout'

def index 
  #  id=params[:filter][:student]

end 

def show 
    puts "im here"


    ids=params[:student].to_i
    print ids
   # puts ids
    @user =Academico::Student.find(params[:id])
end 



private
def historys_params
   params.require(:facturacion_history).permit(:student=>[:id])
end
```

end

**routes.rb**

```
   resources :statements
   resources :historys
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
<div class="">

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Historial Transacciones</h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="x_content">
                    <% if notice.present?%>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a>
                        <%= notice %>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <%= form_tag  facturacion_historys_path, :method => 'get',:class=>"form-horizontal form-label-left" do %>

                             <%= label_tag "Estudiante", nil, :class=>"control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" %>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                   <%= collection_select(:student,:id, Academico::Student.all, :id,:full_name, {:include_blank => true, :required=>"required"},{:class=>"select2_single form-control",:required=>"required"}) %>
                               </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>


                        <div class="clearfix"><br></div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left:100px;">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left:100px;">
                                    <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Generar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the form does not redirect me to the show view, after I choose an option, it returns the same index
he looked for information about it and found no solution my rake routes are as follows

**Rake routes**

```
facturacion/historys#index
                                                             POST   /facturacion/historys(.:format)                                                        facturacion/historys#create
                                     new_facturacion_history GET    /facturacion/historys/new(.:format)                                                    facturacion/historys#new
                                    edit_facturacion_history GET    /facturacion/historys/:id/edit(.:format)                                               facturacion/historys#edit
                                         facturacion_history GET    /facturacion/historys/:id(.:format)                                                    facturacion/historys#show
                                                             PATCH  /facturacion/historys/:id(.:format)                                                    facturacion/historys#update
                                                             PUT    /facturacion/historys/:id(.:format)                                                    facturacion/historys#update
                                                             DELETE /facturacion/historys/:id(.:format)                                                    facturacion/historys#destroy
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong or if I am or mitigating some step, I would be grateful for the help, thank you very much

Comment: There's a typo in the path of your form `facturacion_historys_path` instead of  `facturacion_history_path` (s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form in index.html, you need the correct path `/facturacion/historys/:id` i.e. **facturacion_history_path(:id)** there is a typo in the path.

**Note**: You need add the id of the record as well.